# Divide to lists in sublists with single data

Tags: python

I'm developing a software that has a class that generate a **list** like that:

```
list[Element0,Element1]

list[Element0] contains: 
`Name: S1 ; Min: 0 ; Max: 100`

list[Element1] contains: 
`Name: S2 ; Min: 30 ; Max: 1200`
```

So the whole list contains:

```
[Name: S1 ; Min: 0 ; Max: 100, Name: S2 ; Min: 30 ; Max: 1200]
```

I want to split the list and be able to get the single information.
So I want to have a sublists like that:

```
sublist0[S1,0,100]    
sublist1[S2,30,1200]
```

Comment: `Name: S2 ; Min: 30 ; Max: 1200`  is a`string`. Right?

Comment: Yes, it's string in a list

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and write the initial and desired data in valid Python syntax? Please also use the correct type syntax – e.g. use ``100`` or ``"100"`` if you want integers or strings.

Comment: Also, please be aware [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you try to parse the output of the class, instead of changing the class to provide the output in a more desirable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define a function that does the custom splitting

```
lst=["Name: S1 ; Min: 0 ; Max: 100", "Name: S2 ; Min: 30 ; Max: 1200"]

def mysplit(s):
    return [e.split(":")[1].strip() for e in s.split(";")]

splst = [mysplit(s) for s in lst]
print(splst)
```

Which produces

```
[['S1', '0', '100'], ['S2', '30', '1200']]
```

I leave to you the burden of converting each element to the appropriate type (at present all the fields are strings)